# Calculate e.g. a mean in a list with multi-column data.frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of several data.frames. Each data.frame has several columns.
By using
    `mean(mylist$first_dataframe$a`
I can get the mean for a in this one data.frame.
However I do not know how to calculate over all the data.frames stored in my list or how for specific data.frames.

I could use a loop but I was told that
    `apply()` and its variations are better
I tried using several solutions I found via search but somehow it just doesn't work.
I assume I need to use

```
unlist()
```

Could you provide an example of how to calculate e.g. a mean for a data structure like mine.
A list with several data.frames containing several columns.

Update:
I'm sorry for the confusion. I wanted the grand mean for a specific column in all dataframes.
Thanks to Thomas for providing a working solution for calculating a grand mean for a specific column in all dataframes and to psychometriko for providing a useful solution for calculating means over all columns in all dataframes (& even for the case when not numeric data is involved).

Thanks!

Comment: Do the data frames that make up the components of your list have the same structure (i.e., same number of columns with same names and classes in each column -- number of rows can differ)?

Comment: @psychometriko
They have exactly the same structure

Comment: @Thomas
Last one. So I have a list. This list contains a lot of dataframes which have the same structure. Let's say there are dataframe1 to dataframe5 and each has column "a", "b" and "c".
Now I want the grand mean of "a" for all dataframes combined.

Comment: @Nikita: could you help me out to figure out how to do the same if the column name is also an argument to be taken from the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
set.seed(42)
mylist <- list(a=data.frame(foo=rnorm(10),
                            bar=rnorm(10)),
               b=data.frame(foo=rnorm(10),
                            bar=rnorm(10)),
               c=data.frame(foo=rnorm(10),
                            bar=rnorm(10)))
sapply(do.call("rbind",mylist),mean)

       foo        bar 
 0.1163340 -0.1696556
```

Note: `do.call("rbind",mylist)` returns something similar to what you referred to above with the `unlist` function, and then `sapply`, as referred to by Roland in his answer, just calls the function `mean` on each component (column) of the data.frame that results from the above `do.call` function.

**Edit**: In response to the question of how to deal with non-numeric data.frame components, the below solution admittedly isn't very elegant and I'm sure better ones exist, but here's the first thing I was able to think of:

```
set.seed(42)
mylist <- list(a=data.frame(rand=rnorm(10),
                            lets=sample(LETTERS,10,replace=TRUE)),
               b=data.frame(rand=rnorm(10),
                            lets=sample(LETTERS,10,replace=TRUE)),
               c=data.frame(rand=rnorm(10),
                            lets=sample(LETTERS,10,replace=TRUE)))
sapply(do.call("rbind",mylist),function(x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) mean(x)
})

$rand
[1] -0.02470602

$lets
NULL
```

This basically just creates a custom function that first tests whether each component is numeric and, if it is, returns the mean. If it isn't, it skips it.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. It is what I need and your example works. But how to tell to calculate only "foo" or "bar".
When using this code for the whole list I get lot of warnings (not numeric) and strange results.

Comment: This works as well but this is not the grand mean over all dataframes. It lists each dataframe and its mean for "foo"/"a".

Comment: Or just `mean(do.call("rbind",mylist)$foo)`, if you want a specific variable.

Comment: @Nikita can you clarify? I see just a grand mean for each list component when I test out my code.

Comment: Yes! The last one did it. Thanks a lot!
So basically it takes all rows of "foo" in mylist and calculates the mean. do.call does the magic :)

Comment: @psychometriko I'm sorry if my question was misleading. I wanted the grand mean. But your solution is something I will need as well, so thank you!

Comment: @Nikita I still don't understand what you were saying in regards to my code producing a mean within each data frame as opposed to a grand mean across all data frames. Does your list of data frames have a different structure than `mylist` in my answer?

Comment: Following @Thomas' suggestion, `colMeans(do.call("rbind", mylist))` should do the trick as well.

Comment: @psychometriko Your code 'do.call("rbind",mylist)' gives me grand means for each column. I have not known how to address one specic column. 'mean(do.call("rbind",mylist)$foo)' does it.
I hope I could clarify.

Comment: @flowla I'm sorry for my misleading question wording. I will edit it and add the solution proposed by Thomas as it does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I see, so you were interested only in one specific data frame component this whole time. Then yes, @Thomas's answer is the one you want. My solution will return the grand means for all numeric components of your data frames, and incidentally you could extract only "foo" from this result by calling the following: sapply(do.call("rbind",mylist),function(x) {...})$foo (where the ... in parentheses is the function I gave in my answer above, here shortened for clarity's sake), though this is of course more roundabout than Thomas's answer.

Comment: @psychometriko I'm glad we worked this out. Have updated the question and hope people will find it helpful.

Comment: It's probably helpful for everybody to delete any unnecessary comments here and on the original question.

Comment: @psychometriko.  What about the mean within each list? Meaning an mean foo and mean barr for list a, b, and c?  Is it possible to show this on this question or should I post a new question?

Comment: I think you should post a new question

Answer (score 2):

The whole `do.call('rbind', List)` thing can be quite slow and prone to mishaps. If there is only one column you need the mean for, the best way is:

```
mean(sapply(mylist, function(X) X$rand))
```

It's about 10x faster the the `do.call` method.

Comment: What if the column name is also a argument to be taken from the user?